# How to drop java source from Oracle database properly?

Tags: oracle, plsql, java

I'm a little stuck here with my Java Source. First I want completly drop it from the database, because I want to recompile it, but I can't drop is, because if I execute this command:

```
drop java source "SCHEMA.JAVASOURCENAME";
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-04043: object JAVASOURCENAME does not exist
```

The Javasource itself has this structure (this is the plsql/java code for it):

```
create or replace and compile java source named myjavasource as

import java.io.*;
import some.custom.jar.one.*;
import some.custom.jar.two.*;
import some.custom.jar.three.*;

    public class MyJavaClass
    {
      public static String myjavafunction(String connectString, String identity, String password)
      {
       ...
      }
    }
```

I executed this "create or replace and compile java source..." command as DBA and with my user as well, I don't know if this can be the problem.

So my question is, how can I drop this java source?

My second question is who can I handle the custom jars? I imported them with this command:

```
call dbms_java.loadjava('-genmissing -r -v -force -grant SCHEMA ./some.custom.jar.one.jar');
```

I also executed this as DBA and with my user. If is check the invalid objects:

```
SELECT *
    FROM user_objects
    WHERE object_type like '%JAVA%'
    AND status = 'INVALID'
```

as DBA I see the whole world invalid (lot of Java classes), but when I check this as user I only get the javasource and the java class name in the invalid list (I think it needs some more external jars, what I can't find right now).

So, why is the invalid java object list different as DBA and as user? Do I need to execute the Java source creation and the jar imports as DBA (and ONLY with DBA), or with the database user if I want to use it (the java funtion, what is using the external jars) with all schema users?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each element of a name must be quoted individually:

```
drop java source "SCHEMA"."JAVASOURCENAME";
```

The identifier `"SCHEMA.JAVASOURCENAME"` refers to a java source name `SCHEMA.JAVASOURCENAME` in the *current* schema, e.g. `"VORIAND"."SCHEMA.JAVASOURCENAME"`

Comment: Thanks, it solve the dropping part :) Can you help with the invalid object list and the jar import as well?

Comment: @VORiAND: sorry, never used Java stored procedures. It might be better to split your question into two questions. Asking several things at once in a single question is not such a good idea